# Unable to send email via Powershell script

Tags: powershell, smtp

This is the error I get from running the Powershell script:

```
Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Failure sending mail."
At C:\snapraid\EmailJob.ps1:25 char:1
+ $smtp.send($message)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException
```

Here is the script:

```
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$Username = "sourceaddress@domain.com"
$Password = "dfgdsaqwigzcwetrwrqwqe"

$CurrentDate = Get-Date

$to = "destinationaddress@domain.com"

$subject = "Job completed at $CurrentDate"

$body = "Job completed at $CurrentDate"
$attachment = "C:\pathtofile\jobfile.txt"

$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$message.subject = $subject
$message.body = $body
$message.to.add($to)
$message.from = $to
$message.attachments.add($attachment)

$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
$smtp.EnableSSL = $true
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
$smtp.send($message)
```

I have this running on three other Windows 2022 Standard servers with no issues whatsoever.

I have tried telnetting to port 587 from the failing server - works fine.

I have checked TLS on all servers and they are identical.

I have verified that the email script is unblocked in Powershell.

Checking for log errors in Event Viewer turns up nothing.

I have verified the version of Powershell is the latest on all servers.

I have disabled the firewall temporarily though I don't think that's an issue since I can get to port 587 via Telnet.

Not sure what to do at this point. I'm pulling my hair out.

I received the following error message after running the suggested code:

```
PSMessageDetails      :
Exception             : System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Send" with "1"
                        argument(s): "Failure sending mail." ---> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail.
                        ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing
                        connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An
                        existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
                           at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags
                        socketFlags)
                           at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
                           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                           at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
                           at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartWriting(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count,
                        AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
                           at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count,
                        AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
                           at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
                           at System.Net.DelegatedStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
                           at System.Net.DelegatedStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
                           at System.Net.Mime.EightBitStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
                           at System.Net.DelegatedStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
                           at System.Net.DelegatedStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
                           at System.Net.Mime.EightBitStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
                           at System.Net.DelegatedStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
                           at System.Net.DelegatedStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
                           at System.Net.Base64Stream.FlushInternal()
                           at System.Net.Base64Stream.Close()
                           at System.Net.Mime.MimePart.Send(BaseWriter writer, Boolean allowUnicode)
                           at System.Net.Mime.MimeMultiPart.Send(BaseWriter writer, Boolean allowUnicode)
                           at System.Net.Mail.Message.Send(BaseWriter writer, Boolean sendEnvelope, Boolean
                        allowUnicode)
                           at System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.Send(BaseWriter writer, Boolean sendEnvelope, Boolean
                        allowUnicode)
                           at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
                           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                           at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
                           at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object )
                           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                           at
                        System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.ConvertToMethodInvocationException(Exception
                        exception, Type typeToThrow, String methodName, Int32 numArgs, MemberInfo memberInfo)
                           at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object )
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`3.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                           at
                        System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
                        frame)
TargetObject          :
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException
ErrorDetails          :
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, C:\snapraid\EmailJob.ps1: line 25
                        at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
```

Comment: Have you inspected the SmtpException? `$Error[0] |fl * -Force`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Are you suggesting that I add this command to the bottom of my script and run it?

Comment: I suggest you run `$Error[0] |fl * -Force` immediately after observing the error, yes :) It'll likely reveal more details about _why_ it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like I figured out the problem. Apparently Powershell or some other app had a hold of the text file the email was trying to send. I shut down all apps and restarted Powershell, ran the command with success this time.